# Is it possible to parse a String into Fn(f64)->f64?

Tags: string, parsing, rust

In Rust, is it possible to parse a String whose contents is a function, into a function? For example, consider:

```
let str_function = "fn add_one(x: f64) -> f64{x+1}".to_string();
```

I'd like to parse that string into an actual function to be used. I know Rust doesn't have anything like Python's eval(), but if I know that the function should take only one parameter, `x: f64` and output `f64`, it could in theory be possible. Something like this (where I put Box because I don't think it would be possible without Box for sure):

```
let a: Box<dyn Fn(f64)->f64> = Box::new(str_function.parse::<dyn Fn(f64)->f64>().unwrap());
```

Is that possible in Rust?

Comment: No, Rust does not have reflection capabilities. It's a compiled language like C.

Comment: If you need to run code dynamically determined at runtime, consider using an *embedded language*. Examples [here](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/awesome-rust#scripting) and [here](https://www.boringcactus.com/2020/09/16/survey-of-rust-embeddable-scripting-languages.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into those. 
I know Rust is compiled language. However, if I know exactly function input and function output, does that really contradict reflection capabilities?

Comment: The function signature is honestly the easy part, you still need a *compiler* to *compile* the contents of the function into instructions at runtime.

Comment: You'd essentially have to write the compiler for the function internals. Only by heavily limiting what's allowed in the function body would that be realistic. It would be like writing a calculator app.

Comment: If you really wanted to do this (which is really not a great idea and there are better alternatives as stated earlier), your best bet is probably to invoke `rustc` on the function source (you probably have to tack a `pub extern "C"` out in front), compile with output `cdylib` format, then use something like [`libloading`](https://docs.rs/libloading/latest/libloading/) to load the dynamic library. This is also not that portable since it requires that users have rustc installed (unless you want to bundle rustc with your program which is nasty)

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov I think you don't realize that converting Rust source code into executable machine code is *waaaay* more complicated than a simple `parse()`. There's a whole compiler chain with intermediate steps and everything just to generate the executable assembly. This won't just be convertible into something executable in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no if you want to use the parse method on a string at runtime to create a callable function. There isn't a convenient way to do that with languages like c or rust, because you always need to hop through the hoop of compilation. From what I can tell that is what you want to do, and on that assumption I recommend you follow the advice of the people who have commented.

The story is slightly different if you want to transform a static string into code. `String::parse` can be used to parse any type that implements `FromStr`, and as it happens it is implemented for [`TokenStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.TokenStream.html). So as a point of interest: you can technically parse a string of a function into a callable function. Just not at runtime, and it requires the use of procedural macros([see The Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#function-like-procedural-macros) for an example).